# ListView not Repainting from OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, listview, repaint

I have a button that should sort a ListView using a custom adapter. The button listener is as follows:

```
collectionSort.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sortOrder = -sortOrder;
        Log.d("DBGINF", "Sort Order: " + sortOrder);
        m.sortByTitles(sortOrder);
        m.notifyDataSetChanged();
});
```

The sort order changes as it should, and the data in the array is sorted, the actual view is never updated by the notifyDataSetChanged though. Here's the sortByTitles() method:

```
public void sortByTitles(int dir) {
    if (dir > 0) {
        sort(new StringComparator());
    } else if (dir < 0) {
        sort(new ReverseStringComparator());
    }
    Log.d("Data Set: ", this.getItem(0) + "");
}
```

The `notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't ever update the view inside an `OnClickListener`, but always works properly **outside** one of the OnClickListeners. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Here is the constructor in the Adapter class:

```
public MainMenuArrayAdapter(Context context, CollectionObject[] objects) {
    super(context, R.layout.mainmenurow, objects);
    myContext = context;
}
```

And here's how it gets initialized in the onCreate() method of the Activity:

```
CollectionObject[] sample = new CollectionObject[] { c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6 };
final MainMenuArrayAdapter m = new MainMenuArrayAdapter(this, sample);
```

Where c1 - c6 are just some temporary CollectionObjects for testing.

Comment: What is `myCollections`? Will need to see more code of your adapter.

Comment: I need to see how you initialized you adapter?

Comment: I edited my question with the constructor for the custom Adapter. myCollections is an array that holds all of the CollectionObjects

Comment: I added an example to my answer, I hope it will help you, let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of adapter are you extending? I think you are actually sorting a copy of the items in your adapter. Are you setting myCollections in the adapter again? Btw if you extend ArrayAdapter keep in mind that the adapter itself has a sort method which accept your own comparator.

EDIT:
I wrote a super stupid example with a custom adapter and sorting, you can press menu for sorting items. Hope it will help!

```
public class SortActivity extends ListActivity {

private StupidAdapter stupidAdapter;
private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    list.add("Android-a");
    list.add("Android-b");
    list.add("Android-c");
    list.add("BlackBerry-a");
    list.add("BlackBerry-b");
    list.add("BlackBerry-c");
    list.add("Windows-a");
    list.add("Windows-b");
    list.add("Windows-c");

    // keep in mind that from now on whatever changes you do on list is not reflected on the adapter.
    // the array adapter keeps its own internal data
    stupidAdapter = new StupidAdapter(this, list);
    setListAdapter(stupidAdapter);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    new MenuInflater(this.getApplication()).inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(final MenuItem item) {
    final int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.menu_main_sort_az) {
        stupidAdapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String object1, String object2) {
                return object1.compareTo(object2);
            };
        });
    } else if (id == R.id.menu_main_sort_za) {
        stupidAdapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String object1, String object2) {
                return object2.compareTo(object1);
            };
        });
    }
    stupidAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    return true;
}

class StupidAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    public StupidAdapter(Context context, List<String> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item, list);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View row, final ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        final String item = getItem(position);

        if (row == null) {
            row = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder(row);

            row.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.refreshData(item);

        return row;
    }       

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView title;
        public ViewHolder(View row) {
            this.title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
        }
        public void refreshData(final String text) {
            this.title.setText(text);
        }
    }   

}

}
```

list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffffff">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textColor="#ff000000"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

main_menu.xml (under res/menu)

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">   
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_main_sort_az" android:title="Sort A-Z"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_main_sort_za" android:title="Sort Z-A"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: It's extending ArrayAdapter<CollectionObject>. And yes I know it has that sort method but I wanted a little more control over how and where it gets sorted. I tried using the built-in sort method inside the OnClickListener and nothing happened.

Comment: Since you extend ArrayAdapter you don't need to keep your own array (myCollections), it causes only problems, ArrayAdapter has his own array...

Comment: Hmmm I changed it up to use the superclasse's getItem() and sort() methods, eliminating my own array entirely, but it still does not sort properly. Would it have something to do with the MainMenuArrayAdapter that I wrote being final and accessed from the OnClickListener?

Comment: I added an example to my answer, I hope it will help you, let me know!

Comment: Yes, I have. I was trying to save a bit of processing by avoiding repainting the TextViews if they were already painted, and apparently I didn't implement that right. It's fixed now, I just took out the bit where I reused the row if it wasn't null. Your solution looks good though, thank you!